# Symfony3 doctrine check if collection empty

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

1. have 3 entity Docs, DocsPerm, DocsList

   2. in doctrine i select only Docs + DocsPerm.
   3. Then i check Docs->getDocsList->isEmpty() then all DocsList are selected from database
   4. How to check if DocsList is empty or selected without cause to select all elements from database?
      Thanks.

EDIT:
example

1. have 2 controllers. ( one with Docs+perm, second Docs+DocList)
2. have 1 twig template for 2 controlers. Here i wan't to check

`{% if Docs.DocsList is empty %}` return false
or

`{% if Docs.DocsList.isEmpty %}`return false or

`{% if Docs.DocsList.first is defined %}` get error.

first two get all DocsList elements from db witch i don't need.

Answer (score 1):

Make a service.

Something like

```
$docListChecker->isEmpty($docs);
```

End then make a query that will fetch only count of entities, but not entities themselves.

```
$result = $qb->select('COUNT(l)')
                ->from('YourBundle:docsList' , 'l')
                ->leftJoin('l.docs.','d')
                ->where('d.id = :id')
                ->setParameter('id', $id)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

This service you can pass to twig and check your list as

```
 {% if checker.isEmpty(Docs.DocsList) %}
```

Or even you can make a twig filter and use it like

```
 {% if Docs.DocsList | isListEmpty %}
```

Comment: And again. Make a service. See upd how to use it in twig